# bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

Суть проблемы: если ша-бэнг содержит только только имя файла интерпретатора, то *bash* его не находит и ругается

```
bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Вот Linux на NAS:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.11(2)-release (arm-ffp-linux-uclibcgnueabi)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

$ cat howdy.pl
#!perl

print "Howdy!\n";

$ perl howdy.pl
Howdy!

$ ./howdy.pl
bash: ./howdy.pl: perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

$ hash
hits    command
1    /ffp/bin/bash
2    /ffp/bin/perl
1    /ffp/bin/cat

$ type perl
perl is hashed (/ffp/bin/perl)

$ which perl
/ffp/bin/perl
```

А вот Cygwin 2.5.1 (в 1.7.33 не наблюдал):

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

$ ls -l howdy.pl
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 user group 26 May 20 12:28 howdy.pl

$ cat howdy.pl
#!perl

print "Howdy!\n";

$ perl howdy.pl
Howdy!

$ ./howdy.pl
-bash: ./howdy.pl: perl: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

$ hash
hits    command
2    /usr/bin/bash
2    /usr/bin/perl
1    /usr/bin/chmod
1    /usr/bin/cat
2    /usr/bin/ls

$ type perl
perl is hashed (/usr/bin/perl)

$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

Права на исполнение есть, никаких CR (^M) нет. В Cygwin 2.5.1 проявляется примерно в 50% случаев, т.е. может запуститься, а может и нет.

Проблема, конечно, не великая, но ИМХО так быть не должно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае ошибка возникает из-за того, что строка-*shebang* `#!perl` эквивалентна `#!./perl`. Ваш скрипт пытается выполниться интерпретатором, находящимся в текущей директории, и, соответственно, говорит `bad interpreter: No such file or directory`, потому что в текущей директории у вас нет файла `perl`.

В виде эксперимента: если вы разместите `perl`-интерпретатор рядом со скриптом (что довольно странно), то этой ошибки не будет.

> ...`#!interpreter` is equivalent to `#!./interpreter`, however, it's not of any practical use...

[The #! magic, details about the shebang/hash-bang mechanism on various Unix flavours](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/)

Answer (score 1):

> так быть не должно

согласно [`man execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) относительно указания интерпретатора в [*shebang-е*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)) сказано следующее (выделено мною):

> The interpreter must be a **valid pathname** for an executable which is not itself a script.

стоит заметить, что «обработкой» *shebang-а* занимается не оболочка, а [*загрузчик программ*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC) операционной системы.

и ещё: путь может быть как абсолютный (от корня — `/`), так и относительный (относительно текущего каталога).

---

если указано просто имя, то интерпретатор разыскивается в текущем каталоге. пример:

```
$ echo '#!sh' > file
$ echo 'echo ok' >> file
$ chmod +x file
$ ./file
bash: ./file: sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
$ ln -s /bin/sh .
$ ./file
ok
$ p=$(pwd)
$ cd /bin
$ $p/file
ok
```

---

но ошибочное поведение, возможно, встречается в описанном вами: если «иногда может запуститься».