# Интерпретатор в shebang

Tags: linux, shell

Может ли интерпретатор в shebang быть относительным путем? В каком мане об этом можно узнать?

```
#!../my_program

#!./my_program
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525708/178576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> В каком мане об этом можно узнать?

```
$ man 2 execve
```

или [онлайн](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).

> Может ли интерпретатор в shebang быть относительным путем?

в операционной системе *gnu/linux* — да.

цитата из упомянутого документа: «*The interpreter must be a valid pathname for an executable file*»

если указан относительный путь (`программа` или аналогично `./программа`, `../программа` и т.п.), то он будет относительным к текущему каталогу текущего процесса.

в других (разумееется, речь о posix-совместимых) операционных системах может быть иное поведение, иные требования. ведь [стандартом posix обработка shebang-а не определена](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01):

> 1. The shell reads its input from a file (see sh), from the -c option or from the system() and popen() functions defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017. **If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified**.

Comment: Я там и смотрел, но там явно не указано, должен ли быть абсолютным или относительным. А, например, [на википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) почему-то сказано, что только абсолютным -- in which interpreter is an absolute path to an executable program".

Comment: в других операционных системах — вполне возможно такое ограничение.

Comment: А вот [тут](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#interpreter-script) явно сказано, что может быть относительным -- "apart from an absolute path, the #! line also accepts a relative path"

Comment: То есть раз в мане явно не указано, что должен быть абсолютным, то значит может быть относительным, а на википедии неточная инфа?

Comment: Что интересно, википедия как раз ссылается на вашу онлайн ссылку в этой цитате про абсолютный путь, но такой цитаты по ссылке нет)

Comment: ну, поправьте статью в википедии. со всеми оговорками (см. текст ответа). в википедии вообще предостаточно некорректного. даже в очень серьёзных вещах. например, linux там — не программа (что есть на самом деле), и даже не «операционная система», а «семейство операционных систем».